# Marshaling Arrays as Return Values P/Inoke .NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, pinvoke

I have the following native C function declaration which I want to convert to VB.NET P/Invoke equivalent so as to call it:

```
unsigned char *h5d65bv(const unsigned char *a, const int alen)
```

As you can see, it returns an array of bytes and takes as parameters another array of bytes a and its length (alen).

I used the following signature, which according to .NET errors ("Managed/Unmanaged signature mismatch in 'return value'. ") is not the correct one:

```
<DllImport("mydll.dll", EntryPoint:="h5d65bv", BestFitMapping:=False, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, ThrowOnUnmappableChar:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
    Friend Function h5d65bv(ByVal a As Byte(), <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> ByVal alen As Int32) As Byte()
    End Function
```

So, which one is the correct "signature" (it must have something to do with arrays and pointers but I didn't find anything on the Internet concerning arrays as **return types**)?

Comment: A name like `h5d65bv` is a very strong hint that you'll have a *lot* of trouble ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the return type is just a pointer to an unsigned char. The number of characters allocated depends on the implementation of the function and .NET has no way of knowing that.

What you can do is make the return type on the .NET part an `IntPtr`, then copying the array manually using [`Marshall.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But that assumes you *have* to know the length of the array.

```
Dim ptr As IntPtr = h5d65bv(input, input.Length)
Dim output As New Byte(100)
Marshall.Copy(ptr, output, 0, 100)
```

---

Another point is that you might have to free the allocated memory, but that again depends on how the `h5d65bv` function allocates it.

Comment: The function allocates the array using simple malloc statement. The length of the returned array is ALWAYS 20 (meaning it has 20 bytes stored, nothing more, nothing less)